# Maven build profiles in a mutli-module project property expansion

Tags: java, maven, properties-file

I have a Multi-Module Maven project. My parent POM has the following modules:

```
<module>common</module>
<module>ingest</module>
<module>package</module>
```

The `package` modules handles all aspects of building a deployable zip file using `maven-antrun-plugin`. The other two modules are where the core application code is located. Within the `package` I have various profiles holding the configuration settings for production, staging and development environments. Each profile looks like:

```
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
     <properties>
          <oozie.url>http://oozie-server:11000/oozie</oozie.url>
          <stage.user>prod-stage</stage.user>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

This works perfectly at the parent level, running:

```
mvn clean install -P prod
```

All the .properties file have the various properties expanded to be the ones in the Maven profile.

Within the `ingest` module, one class may rely upon a .properties file with the `ingest` module. The contents of this properties file will look something like:

```
stageUser=${stage.user}
```

When running tests for the `ingest` module, the properties are not expanded to be the properties from the build profile e.g. the property will still be `stageUser=${stage.user}` rather than `stageUser=prod-stage`. This causes the test to fail.

The only workaround I have is to add in the required profiles and properties to get the test to pass into the `ingest` POM. This means I have these properties in two locations both the `package` and `ingest` modules. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inheritance of properties from the parent should work. Make sure you have the `parent` declaration in the child modules:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>parentGroupId</groupId>
    <version>version</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks manouti! I just moved the profiles section into the parent POM and fixed the problem